# Facebook private messages email notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to receive email notification on about new Facebook messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/how-to-receive-email-notification-on-about-new-facebook-messages)

I used to get email notifications when I received private messages but for some reason I'm not getting the notifications any more. I went to Account Settings -> Notifications but I'm not finding any option to turn this on.

How can I get email notifications when I receive a private message?

Answer (score 0):

You already found the correct page. In the section "All Notifications" click on "Facebook" (first entry in my case), it will unfold and contain several options, one of them "Sends you a message" - tick it and click on "Save Changes".

This link will bring you directly to the settings: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=Facebook&view

Facebook thread discussing the issue asked for
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151356356883086

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that when I go to Notifications-->Facebook all I get is this message "You'll see every notification on Facebook, but you can turn off notifications about specific posts as you view them." and a button to Close. I have nothing to edit there. And when I go to Notifications-->Email I can edit several options but I have no one for private messages.

Comment: I don't see this option either. Apparently some users have different options than others. You can read more in the comments on this response: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22198/30406