# How to receive email notification of new Facebook messages in 2019?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-notifications

This is a follow-up to this question: [How to receive email notification of new Facebook messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/how-to-receive-email-notification-of-new-facebook-messages).

Facebook changed their notification options, so neither the accepted answer nor the screenshot in the aforementioned question apply any more.

---

**I'd like to receive an e-mail message whenever someone sends me a Facebook message.** What do I need to do? I checked the [Notifications Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) configuration page, which contains the following categories:

- Comments
- Tags
- Reminders
- More Activity About You
- Updates From Friends
- Friend Requests
- People You May Know
- Birthdays
- Groups
- Video
- Events
- Pages You Follow
- Marketplace
- Fundraisers and Community Support
- Other Notifications

I've read all their descriptions, and none of them mentions private messages. What did I miss?

Comment: The thing to do is not to create a duplicate question, but to open a bounty on the original question and point out the answers are out-dated.

Comment: @ale: Are you sure that's the way to go? We'd have to (a) fix the outdated question, (b) get a mod to unaccept the accepted answer (since the original asker is not active any more), (c) wait for someone to provide a correct answer, (d) get the community to upvote it more then the old (previously valid) answers or downvote the old answers (not really fair, since they were good and valid answers) or (e) get a mod to accept the new, valid answer. Seems quite complicated, which is why I opted for a new question in this case. With a new question, we just need step (c).