# How to receive email notification of new Facebook messages (2021)

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-messenger, facebook-notifications

I would like to receive an email when someone sends me a message on Facebook. This used to happen by default until October 2020.

Is it still possible to set it up somehow?

Are email notifications still available?

Answer (score 2):

I went and looked in the [usual place](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) where we would set notifications for our email and indeed it seems Messenger option isn't present. There was [another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/how-to-receive-email-notification-of-new-facebook-messages) asked how to enable on it, and comments on the top answer reflect the same.

Seems they got rid of the ability to get messenger posts via email, although I couldn't find any official announcement for the same.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So you are not getting such email in a case I described? Did you in the past?

Comment: Yeah I disabled it few years back for sure. Went and looked after your question, nothing. Even when I made the notifications to send every update to email it doesn't send you anymore. Seems they phased it out in favor of people using their Messenger app/website.